# php json parse access child values

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to filter and later access to the child data of a nested json file using PHP but for now i'm unable to do it.

Json example:

```
{ "_embedded": {
        "items": [
            {
                "uuid": "zL7j58B5fC3",
                "dns_records": [
                    {
                        "type": "TXT",
                        "name": "_amazonses1.test.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TXT",
                        "name": "_ddplatform1.test.com"
                    }    
                ]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "Zf6Yr2n07",
                "dns_records": [
                    {
                        "type": "TXT",
                        "name": "_amazonses2.test.com",
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TXT",
                        "name": "_ddplatform2.test.com"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried with this code:

```
$data = json_decode($resp, true);
if( ! empty( $data ) ) {
    foreach($data['_embedded']['items'] as $item){
      if($item['uuid'] == $domain_id){
          $dns_entries=$item['uuid']['dns_records']['name'];
     } else {
          $dns_entries = '';
     }
      echo $dns_entries;
}
```

So $domain_id is an external value that I passed through the function. The idea is that if it matches one of the child's values, then I can extract the values inside that child.

If I pass $domain_id as Zf6Yr2n07 then I need to extract the TXT information (name) inside that child node. e.g. _amazonses2.test.com

Any tip will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `dns_records` is an array. You need to iterate through the array and extract values based on type. `$dns_entries=$item['uuid']['dns_records']['name'];` can be `$dns_entries=$item['uuid']['dns_records'][array_index]['name'];`

Comment: _"Json example:"_ - that's not valid JSON to begin with, so the attempt to decode it will fail already.

Comment: i'm sorry about the wrongly formated json, it was due to copy and paste sections of the json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your JSON is invalid. Make sure to remove trailing commas.

Second, you're accessing `$item["uuid"]["dns_records"]["name"]`, but

1. `dns_records` is an array
2. `dns_records` exists on `$item`, not `$item["uuid"]`

To get only the first name, just select the first element inside the `dns_records` array: `$item["dns_records"][0]["name"]`

Another option is to return an array with all the available names by looping through all child elements of `dns_records` and pushing the `name` to a new array:

```php
if( ! empty( $data ) ) {
    $dns_entries = [];
    foreach($data['_embedded']['items'] as $item){
        if($item['uuid'] == $domain_id){
            foreach($item['dns_records'] as $dns_item) {
                $dns_entries[] = $dns_item["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($dns_entries); // print_r because echo doesn't work with arrays
}
```

[Live demo on onlinephp.io](https://onlinephp.io/c/098ae)

Comment: oh man thanks for the code! this is exactly what i've looking for. Sorry for the errors on the json file, copy and pasted between screen delivers to that. Thanks @EinLinuus.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if( ! empty( $data ) ) {
foreach($data['_embedded']['items'] as $item){
  if($item['uuid'] == $domain_id){
      $dns_entries_0=$item['uuid']['dns_records'][0]['name'];
      $dns_entries_1=$item['uuid']['dns_records'][1]['name'];
 } else {
      $dns_entries = '';
 }
  echo $dns_entries;
```

}

Comment: thanks for your suggestions also! Kezman10

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).